# When to use dispatch_once versus reallocation? (Cocoa/CocoaTouch)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I often use simple non compile-time immutable objects: like an array `@[@"a", @"b"]` or a dictionary `@{@"a": @"b"}`.

I struggle between reallocating them all the time:

```
- (void)doSomeStuff {
    NSArray<NSString *> *fileTypes = @[@"h", @"m"];
    // use fileTypes
}
```

And allocating them once:

```
- (void)doSomeStuff {
    static NSArray<NSString *> * fileTypes;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        fileTypes = @[@"h", @"m"];
    });
    // use fileTypes
}
```

Are there recommendations on when to use each construct? Like:

- depending on the size of the allocated object
- depending on the frequency of the allocation
- depending on the device (iPhone 4 vs iMac 2016)
- ...

How do I figure it out?

Comment: I don't see any reasons to use dispatch_once. I think that the best way: static NSArray<NSString *> * fileTypes = nil; ...  if ( ! fileTypes) { fileTypes = @[@"h", @"m"]; }  ...  return fileTypes;

Comment: @oxigen The use of `dispatch_once` is thread safe. Using `if (!fileTypes)` is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes. But in this case we don't need a thread safe method.

Comment: @oxigen How do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

Your bullet list is a good start. Memory would be another consideration. A `static` variable will stay in memory from the time it is actually initialized until the termination of the app. Obviously a local variable will be deallocated at the end of the method (assuming no further references).

Readability is something to consider too. The reallocation line is much easier to read than the `dispatch_once` setup.

For a little array, I'd reallocate as the first choice. The overhead is tiny. Unless you are creating the array in a tight loop, performance will be negligible.

I would use `dispatch_once` and a `static` variable for things that take more overhead such as creating a date formatter. But then there is the overhead of reacting to the user changing the device's locale.

In the end, my thought process is to first use reallocation. Then I consider whether there is tangible benefit to using `static` and `dispatch_once`. If there isn't a worthwhile reason to use a `static`, I leave it a local variable.

Use `static` if the overhead (speed) of reallocation is too much (but not if the permanent memory hit is too large).

Comment: Since the data is stored statically $whereever, I do not think that the allocation of the encapsulating object has a memory footprint one can take into account. In his case these are string literals, which are always stored statically.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, those where just basic examples, and rmaddy is correct about cases with an NSDateFormatter or similar costly instances.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is more complex. So you should use it, if it is needed, but not as a default.

Typically this is done when the object creating is extreme expensive (almost never) or if you need a single identity of the instance object (shared instance, sometimes called singleton, what is incorrect.) In such a case you will recognize that you need it.

Comment: I also came to this conclusion for simple cases. But for costly instances or high frequency access, I do not know when to start optimising.

Comment: You start with optimization, when you need it. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." (Donald Knuth)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question could probably be closed as "primarily opinion-based", I think this question addresses a choice that programmers frequently make.

The obvious answer is: don't optimize, and if you do, profile first - because most of the time you'll intuitively address the wrong part of your code.

That being said, here's how I address this.

- If the needed object is expensive to build (like the formatters per documentation) and lightweight on resources, reuse / cache the object.
- If the object is cheap to build, create a new instance when needed.
- For crucial things that run on the main thread (UI stuff) I tend to draw the line more strict and cache earlier.

Depending on what you need those objects for, sometimes there are valid alternatives that are cheaper but offer a similar programming comfort. For example, if you wanted to look up some chessboard coordinates, you could either build a dictionary {@"a1" : 0, @"b1" : 1, ...}, use an array alone and the indices, take a plain C array (which now has a much less price tag attached to it), or do a small integer-based calculation.

Another point to consider is where to put the cached object. For example, you could store it statically in the method as in your example. Or you could make it an instance variable. Or a class property / static variable. Sometimes caching is only the half way to the goal - if you consider a table view with cells including a date formatter, you can think about reusing the very same formatter for all your cells. Sometimes you can refactor that reused object into a helper object (be it a singleton or not), and address some issues there.

So there is really no golden bullet here, and each situation needs an individual approach. Just don't fall into the trap of premature optimization and trade clear code for bug-inviting, hardly readable stuff that might not matter to your performance but comes with sure drawbacks like increased memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

**dispatch_once_t**

This allows two major benefits: 1) a method is guaranteed to be called only once, during the lifetime of an application run, and 2) it can be used to implement **lazy initialization**, as reported in the Man Page below.

*From the [OS X Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html) for `dispatch_once()`:*

> The dispatch_once() function provides a simple and efficient mechanism to run an initializer exactly once, similar to pthread_once(3).  Well designed code hides the use of lazy initialization.

*Some use cases for dispatch_once_t*

1. Singleton
2. Initialization of a file system resource, such as a file handle
3. Any static variable that would be shared by a group of instances, and takes up a lot of memory

**static, without dispatch_once_t**

A statically declared variable that is not wrapped in a `dispatch_once` block still has the benefit of being shared by many instances. For example, if you have a static variable called `defaultColor`, all instances of the object see the same value. It is therefore class-specific, instead of instance-specific.

However, any time you need a guarantee that a block will be called only once, you will need to use `dispatch_once_t`.

**Immutability**

You also mentioned immutability. Immutability is independent of the concern of running something once and only once--so there are cases for both static immutable variables and instance immutable variables. For instance, there may be times when you need to have an immutable object initialized, but it still may be different for each instance (in cases where it's value depends on other instance variables). In that case, an immutable object is not static, and still may be initialized with different values from multiple instances. In this case, a property is derived from other instance variables, and therefore should not be allowed to be changed externally.

*A note on immutability vs mutability, from [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html):*

> Consider a scenario where all objects are capable of being mutated. In your application you invoke a method and are handed back a reference to an object representing a string. You use this string in your user interface to identify a particular piece of data. Now another subsystem in your application gets its own reference to that same string and decides to mutate it. Suddenly your label has changed out from under you. Things can become even more dire if, for instance, you get a reference to an array that you use to populate a table view. The user selects a row corresponding to an object in the array that has been removed by some code elsewhere in the program, and problems ensue. Immutability is a guarantee that an object won’t unexpectedly change in value while you’re using it.
>
> Objects that are good candidates for immutability are ones that encapsulate collections of discrete values or contain values that are stored in buffers (which are themselves kinds of collections, either of characters or bytes). But not all such value objects necessarily benefit from having mutable versions. Objects that contain a single simple value, such as instances of NSNumber or NSDate, are not good candidates for mutability. When the represented value changes in these cases, it makes more sense to replace the old instance with a new instance.

*A note on performance, from the [same reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html):*

> Performance is also a reason for immutable versions of objects representing things such as strings and dictionaries. Mutable objects for basic entities such as strings and dictionaries bring some overhead with them. Because they must dynamically manage a changeable backing store—allocating and deallocating chunks of memory as needed—mutable objects can be less efficient than their immutable counterparts.